# Local-Global divisibility of points on elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve and $P \in E(\mathbb{Q})$. If $P$ is divisible by $p$ in $E(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ for every prime $p$, does it follow that $P$ is a torsion point?

Comment: A torsion point of order $n$ won’t be divisible by primes dividing $n$. Do you want to allow divisibility by all but finitely many $p$?

Comment: @Lubin: if $E(\mathbb{Q})$ has four points then a point of order 2 will be divisible by p for all p.

Comment: If there are infinitely many anomalous primes (i.e. $a_p=-1$) then such a point must be $O$. However when there is a rational torsion point then there are only finitely many anomalous primes. My intuition says that it is true (and it says that either $P=O$ or $2P=O$) but I am not sure I know how to prove this. How does this condition arise?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich this question is in a simplified setup of where my original question occurs. Let $K$ be a quadratic imaginary field and $y_K \in E(K)$ be a Heegner point. I've been wondering about divisibility of Heegner points by $p$ in $E(K_v)$ where $v$ is a prime of $K$ above $p$ and I ask if for every prime $v$ of $K$ $y_K$ is divisible by $p$ in $E(K_v)$ where $p$ is the rational prime below $v$, does this imply that $y_K$ is a torsion point?

Comment: A well-taken point, @ChrisWuthrich, but only half. If the $2$-power torsion is $C_2\oplus C_2$, not so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chris Wuthrich has already provided an answer when there are infinitely many anomalous primes, with the correction that the condition to be anomalous is $a_p=1$, i.e. the number of points in the reduction modulo $p$ is $p$. In the case of non-anomalous prime, the condition that $P$ is $p$-adically divisible by $p$ is equivalent to $p$ being an elliptic Wieferich prime with respect to $E,P$ in the sense of Silverman (J. Number Theory 1988). There it is proved that, assuming the abc conjecture, there will be non-Wieferich primes in some cases if $P$ is of infinite order, which answers your question in the affirmative. There are many papers following up on this. Just as in the classical case of Wieferich primes, one expects very few of them so the answer to your question is almost certainly yes but we can't prove much uncondionally.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I was completely unaware of these results